# How do I find weighted average in r?

Tags: r, vector, average

I want to calculate a students grade in your course. I came up with steps needed to be done but I am having trouble following all the way through.

- Create a vector called 'report_card' that contains, in this order, 92, 88, 91, 97, 85.
- Create another vector called 'assignments' with the assignment names, in this order, HW1, Exam 1, Quiz, Exam 2, HW2
- Assign the names for the 'report_card' grades with the 'assignments'
- Calculate the student's grade in the class if exams are 50% of the grade, quizzes are 30% and homework is 20%. Assign answer to 'student_grade'

So far I have the vectors

```
report_card <- c(92,88,91,97,85)
assignments <- c("HW1", "Exam 1", "Quiz", "Exam 2", "HW2")
```

I don't know how to link them or where to go from there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Good question! There are a lot of ways to do this in R but here's a simple approach just using vectors:

The trick I used was indexing a vector by another vector in order to match each grade with a weight. First, I pulled in your example data:

```r
> assignments <- c("HW1", "Exam 1", "Quiz", "Exam 2", "HW2")
> report_card <- c(92, 88, 91, 97, 85)
```

To calculate an arithmetic mean, we need to be able to program with both the scores and the weights together. To do this, I first created a mapping between them using a *named vector* based upon a quick coding scheme for each *type* of grade:

```r
> weights <- c("H"=20, "Q"=30, "E"=50)
> assignment_types <- c("H", "E", "Q", "E", "H")
```

This lets us find the absolute weight each assignment should get by indexing one vector with the other:

```r
> weights[assignment_types]
 H  E  Q  E  H 
20 50 30 50 20
```

See how R match the names of the `weights` named vector to the values in the `assignment_types` vector?

Now that we have a way to get the weight for each assignment, we can calculate the weighted grade like:

```r
> (student_grade <- sum(report_card * weights[assignment_types]) / sum(weights[assignment_types]))
[1] 91.29412
```

Because this is R, there are tons of ways you could do this. A tidier approach might use `data.frame`s but the `vector`-based approach seems to work well here.

Answer (score 1):

I always like to do the `dplyr` version.

```
library(dplyr)

report_card <- c(92,88,91,97,85)
assignments <- c("HW1", "Exam 1", "Quiz", "Exam 2", "HW2")

# get rid of the numbers here (and the whitespaces)
assignments <- gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", assignments)
assignments <- gsub(" ", "", assignments)

assignment_weights <- data.frame(assignments = c("HW", "Exam", "Quiz")
                                 , weights = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.3))

# now put both into a dataframe
df <- data.frame(report_card, assignments)

# now take this dataframe and...
df %>%
    group_by(assignments) %>% # for every assignment type
    summarise(avgGrade_byAssignmentType = mean(report_card)) %>% # you calculate the average...
    left_join(assignment_weights, by = "assignments") %>% # now you add the weights
    summarise(finalGrade = weighted.mean(avgGrade_byAssignmentType, weights)) # and calculate a weighted average
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like below?

```
ws <- sum(sapply(c("HW","Quiz","Exam"), function(x) mean(report_card[grepl(x,names(report_card))]))*c(0.2,0.3,0.5))
```

or

```
ws <- (c(0.2,0.3,0.5)%*%sapply(c("HW","Quiz","Exam"), function(x) mean(report_card[grepl(x,names(report_card))])))[1]
```

such that

```
> ws
[1] 91.25
```

**DATA**

```
report_card <- c(HW1 = 92, `Exam 1` = 88, Quiz = 91, `Exam 2` = 97, HW2 = 85
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `weighted.mean` to *calculate a weighted average*.

```
wgt  <- c(HW=20, Quiz=30, Exam=50)
weighted.mean(report_card, 
 wgt[match(gsub("^([[:alpha:]]+).*","\\1",assignments), names(wgt))])
#[1] 91.29412
```

With `wgt` the weights are defined. With `gsub` only the beginning of `assignments` are taken and those are used to `match` to the names of `wgt`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution might be a bit more verbose, but by using a `data.frame` and some `dplyr` logic, we can easily build a readable and reproducible pipeline for this analysis to be run on multiple students.

Suppose we create a `data.frame` that can include multiple students.

```
student <- rep("john doe", 5)
report_card <- c(92,88,91,97,85)
assignments <- c("HW1", "Exam 1", "Quiz", "Exam 2", "HW2")

data <- data.frame(student, report_card, assignments)
```

We will then first assign a standardized variable for each assignment. By grouping by student and this standardized variable, we can calculate the average score for each type of assignment for each student.

Calculating the total grade is then easy by performing a second `summarise` to sum the weighted average scores per type of assignment.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(assignment_standardized  = case_when(
    grepl("Exam", assignments) ~ "E",
    grepl("Quiz", assignments) ~ "Q",
    grepl("HW", assignments) ~ "H",
    TRUE ~ ""
  )) %>% 
  group_by(student, assignment_standardized) %>% 
  summarise(report_normalized  = mean(report_card)) %>% 
  summarise(student_grade = 
              report_normalized[assignment_normalized == "E"] * 0.5 + 
              report_normalized[assignment_normalized == "Q"] * 0.3 +
              report_normalized[assignment_normalized == "H"] * 0.2
            )
```